# Error: didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, button

I want to press a button in an html-template

```
              <form action="{% url 'speech2text' %}" class="card-text" method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Start</button>
              </form>

              <p> Sie haben das folgende gesagt: </p>
              <p> {{ speech_text }} </p>
```

by pressing the button, the code in the following view shall be executed and send back the result into the template:

```
def speech2textView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="de-DE")
            args = {'speech_text': text}
            return render(request, 'speech2text.html', args)
```

Whats wrong here? many thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like somehow you are calling the view with a method which is not POST, in that case your view is not returning anything (thus is actually returning None). Your form looks right though.

Comment: you should use `print()` to check if `request.method` have value `"POST"` and if `text` gets any string from google. You should also check if you don't get any error when run it. And I assume that you run django on local computer because django on server don't have access to your local microphone.

Comment: many thanks for you support. POST works well and the text is correct when I run it in python. good point with the microphone. what do you suggest? do I need to catch the voice by the frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because there was no return! It seems that `return render(request, 'speech2text.html', args)` doesn't work. Try adding `return render()` outside of the `with`, and if the same error occurs try adding that outside of the `request.method == "POST":`. This way u can check where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the code again and now it is working. I would like to share this. Many thanks to this community.

```
def speech2textView(request):
    args = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.method)
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="de-DE")
            args = {'speech_text': text}
    return render(request, 'speech2text.html', args)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to checking the context with adding a print command and inspecting in your command window like this

```
def speech2textView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="de-DE")
            args = {'speech_text': text}
            print(args)
            return render(request, 'speech2text.html', args)
```

if you didn't see the data in your command window I think the problem is in your recognition step or on the request step keep tracking with printing some data to see where is the code stuck or fail.

Comment: the recognizer works well. I have tested with python. you speak into mic and the text appears. I moved the return() statement to the left, but then I got the error: "UnboundLocalError at /speech2text/, local variable 'args' referenced before assignment".

Comment: another test results to: "POST" request works fine. By clicking the button, a POST request comes up. There is something wrong in the code starting from "with sr.Microphone ...